# Word for "blissfully oblivious"?

Tags: single-word-requests, idiom-requests

Is there an English word or idiom that describes a person who's blissfully unaware or oblivious to their surroundings? I always thought this word was "aloof," but "aloof" seems to hold a rather negative connotation, whereas the word I'm looking would almost connote a positive, like "living in a fairy tale" - or something along these lines. Is there a word for this, or is "oblivious" as close as we get?

Comment: The word that is closest to *oblivious* is, believe it or not, *oblivious*!

Comment: There’s ***clueless***

Comment: The person is "in his own world" (or in a world of his own),  staying in his thoughts and ​ideas and not giving much ​attention to what is ​happening around him.

Comment: What's wrong with *bliss?* "informal: reach a state of perfect happiness, typically so as **to be oblivious of everything else**." *"blissed-out hippies"* –Google

Comment: I'm confused by this question. You used an idiom and the exact word as part of the question. Surely the answer is simply _yes_

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A `Lotus Eater` .

1. Classical Mythology. a member of a people whom Odysseus found
   existing in a state of languorous forgetfulness induced by their
   eating of the fruit of the legendary lotus; one of the lotophagi.
2. a person who leads a life of dreamy, indolent ease, indifferent to the busy world; daydreamer.

Comment: I love this! Most unique by far - thanks for sharing!

Comment: Happy spreading the word. Read it aeons back in some book and it came to me right as I read this question.

Answer (score 8):

An idiomatic phrase for this is ***blissfully unaware.***

***[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=blissfully%20unaware%2C%20blissfully%20oblivious&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cblissfully%20unaware%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cblissfully%20oblivious%3B%2Cc0):*** *blissfully unaware*.

Comment: Backed by science, I love it!

Comment: Thanks @josh61 - I'll get the hang of this eventually (I hope).

Answer (score 5):

Consider *[head in the clouds](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/head-in-the-clouds)*

> guided by whim and fancy

*thefreedictionary.com*

However,this term has a connotation of *flighty*, which may not be considered positive.

A similar concept is *[on cloud nine](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/on-cloud-nine)*

> elated; very happy

*Collins*

Comment: This was a super close second, as `head in the clouds` absolutely nails it! Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 3):

**Out to lunch.**

> 1. Informal
>      Unaware of or inattentive to present conditions.

https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=define%20out%20to%20lunch

Answer (score 2):

***[Be/live in a dream world](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/live+in+a+dream+world)***  may convey the idea:

> - to have ideas or hopes which are not practical and are not likely to be successful (usually in continuous tenses) :
>
>   - *If she thinks he's suddenly going to turn into the perfect boyfriend, she's living in a dream world.*

(Cambridge Idioms Dictionary)

Answer (score 2):

***zoned-out***

> zone out
>
> Stop paying attention, dissociate oneself from a situation. Also, engage in a mindless activity. For example, *When Felicia starts talking about her ailments and her friends' ailments,* *I totally zone out.* This idiom also occurs in the passive, be zoned out. It originally alluded to narcotic intoxication and then was broadened to other kinds of dissociation. [; second half of 1900s]
>
> [The American Heritage® Idioms Dictionary](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/zone-out)

***space cadet***

> (*slang, derogatory*) One who forgets, daydreams, or otherwise is distracted from reality more often than most.
>
> [Wiktionary](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/space_cadet)

***spaced-out***

> dreamily or eerily out of touch with reality; disoriented, forgetful, or dazed. [1965–70, Amer.]
>
> [Random House Kernerman Webster's College Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/spaced-out)

Answer (score 2):

~ Ditzy

silly or scatterbrained.
"don't tell me my ditzy secretary didn't send you an invitation!"
synonyms:   silly, foolish, giddy, lightheaded, scatterbrained, featherbrained, harebrained, empty-headed, vacuous, stupid, brainless

From: Wikipedia

Comment: This doesn't imply blissfulness, though.

Answer (score 1):

Without more context, I would go with "naive." It connotes not only ignorance, but unawareness that there is something to be ignorant *of*. It's often used to describe children or immature people.

Answer (score 1):

blithe

1. of a happy lighthearted character or disposition
2. lacking due thought or consideration :  casual, heedless

--blithe·ly adverb

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/blithe

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget - **ignorance is bliss**

> if you do not know about something, you do not worry about it.