# Is there any word/term for when we not only don't know something but don't even think about it?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, verbs

Sometimes we don't know something but we know that we don't know it.

> I don't know what is his intention, whether he intends good or bad. I should find out.

But sometimes we even don't know that we don't know. We are just empty-minded about the matter. We are behind the point where we start to consider it.

> She ... on his intention. She is totally ... about it. Or maybe there are other ways to say that.

What is the word/term?

Comment: Closely related, but unfortunately the question is closed: [Word for “blissfully oblivious”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/314162/word-for-blissfully-oblivious)

Comment: Also very closely related: [What is a term for someone who doesn't know what they haven't experienced?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/125524/what-is-a-term-for-someone-who-doesnt-know-what-they-havent-experienced)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

She is totally **oblivious**.

See definition [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/oblivious):

> lacking remembrance, memory, or mindful attention
>
> lacking active conscious knowledge or awareness

Comment: Isn't "oblivious" just for when there is something like a danger/damage involved?

Comment: It is just as well used neutrally. *oblivious to a surprise party* *she doesn't know of the new president, she's oblivious*.

Answer (score 0):

***Unawareness***, state of being [unaware](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/unaware):

> not understanding or realizing something:
>
> - *[ + that ] He was unaware that the police were watching him.
>   I was completely unaware of the problem.*

(Cambridge Dictionary)

- She is totally unaware of (the problem, etc.)